# Visual Studio 2013 Android SDK Manager not working

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, sdk, xamarin.android

In Visual Studio 2013 when I go to Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager, the dialog is not showing up. In the Xamarin Diagnostics, I get the following:

```
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Jimmy\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\Android\sdk\tools\android.bat'
[W:]:                     Adb connection refused
[I:]:                     Starting Adb server (adb start-server)
[I:]:                     Adb start-server operation completed
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     avd watcher error: load process of avd devices failed, please check the following error: The system cannot find the path specified.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

From another SO post I've seen that a possible solution is to add set `java_exe="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe"`
under find_java.bat within the `Android\sdk\tools\lib folder`. That didnt fix the issue either. Before going through the painful process to uninstall and reinstall everything, is there anything I can do? I ran out of ideas...

Comment: I've had trouble with this too although my error is slightly different.

I note that Adb has started ok - because it has correctly returned a list with zero devices. You can do this yourself on the command line. Also your "avd watcher" paths are also similar enough to be right.

SO... The underlying issue is within the program that is the "avd watcher" which I guess comes from the VS stuff.

In your case, it wants to run something is installed in C:\Program Files xxx\ and the program doesn't like the space. 
Now to find out what it is and kill it. Thanks Microsoft (or Xamarin?)....

Comment: @RobVonNesselrode Xamarin is Microsoft.